# Htaccess, Directory-Style not rewriting to query-style

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a very basic htaccess, attempting to convert directory-style to query style.
i.e.

```
a. /public_html/main/folder1/folder2     ... etc
b. /public_html/main.php?1=folder1&1=folder2
```

No matter what regex I try, to matter what rewrite rule I try - I can't make any progress on this problem.

I've searched the web, many times so far. I've tried 10 different 'recommended' solutions found in other forums.

I don't know where else to look.
Here's my current htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^public_html/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ main.php?name=$1&page=$2 [NC]
```

Here's my httpd.conf Htaccess directives.

```
(Directory "/Users/admin/Sites")
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
(/Directory)
(Directory "/Users/admin/Sites/MFCS/V3/public_html/mfcs/public_html")
    AllowOverride  All
(/Directory)
```

I replaced the greater than / less than on the directory tags for this example.

the httpd.conf does have the proper tags in it.

Comment: And what URL are you trying?

Comment: I missed your comment, sorry Jon !
Here's the url:
http://localhost/~admin/MFCS/V3/public_html/mfcs/public_html/main.php

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/main/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /main.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This will redirect requests to:

```
http://www.example.com/main/folder1/folder2
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/main.php?name=folder1&page=folder2
```

If this is not the outcome your looking for please provide a sample before and after. On  another note did you make sure to enable `mod_rewrite`? I also removed the `public_html` from the URI because it's normally **not visible** to the public.

Comment: If I test mod_rewrite via
 <?php echo in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()); ?>
1:
Select all
Open in new window
- it return true.

I copy/pasted your suggestion, and i can go to the local address:
`code`http://localhost/~admin/MFCS/V3/public_html/mfcs/public_html/main/csbg,`code`

and main.php is loading fine, however - $_GET is still empty.